# Why to use ! symbol and then escape it?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter a name"
read name
    case "$name" in
            *[!\ a-zA-Z]*)  echo "Can contain only alphabets" >/dev/tty
            continue;;
            *) echo "Good entry" ;;
    esac
```

Comment: Test your expression on http://regexr.com/ and find out what happens when you remove the part that bothers you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
*[!\ a-zA-Z]*
```

Has `!` at the start which does negation of all characters or ranges present inside `[...]`. In this case it means anything that is

- not a space
- not in the range of `a-z`
- not in the range of `A-Z`

**Also note that escaping is for space next to `\` not for the preceding `!`** to avoid word splitting.